# What is the POSIX defined behavior of <> when used in a redirect?

Tags: shell, posix

Files can be opened in read-write mode and interacted with like so:

```
exec 4<> myfile

reader < myfile
writer >> myfile
```

The following code **also works**, and is simpler:

```
reader <> myfile
writer >> myfile
```

This makes me believe that `<>` opens the file in read-write mode, but behaves as `<` when used as a redirect. The only information I can find on the behavior of `<>` is related to its use with `exec`. I cannot find any documentation anywhere on whether or not its behavior when used as a redirect is actually defined, or if is implementation dependent.

Is this behavior defined in the POSIX specification anywhere? Is it portable?

Comment: What is supposed to be the use of `&` just before `4`? Just a smart confusing way of writing the two commands `exec &` and `4<>myfile`? That is different from both `exec 4<>myfile` (which was probably intended) and `exec 4<>myfile &`.

Comment: @mosvy you're right. That was a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [2017 IEEE standards for "Shell Command Language"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> 2.7.7 Open File Descriptors for Reading and Writing
>
> The redirection operator:
>
> [n]<>word
>
> shall cause the file whose name is the expansion of word to be opened for both reading and writing on the file descriptor denoted by n, or standard input if n is not specified. If the file does not exist, it shall be created.

Thus, any compliant shell should respect in-out redirection.

Comment: An example of non-compliant shell is ksh93, where `<>file` without an explicit fd will redirect the stdout (1), not the stderr (0) to `file`. That was fixed in recent versions ("ksh2020").

Comment: "or standard input if n is not specified"... Does that mean that `command <> file` will always open `file` in read/write and `command` will have it connected to its standard input?